# Jest snapshots with nested components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've created a snapshot test for a component that have many children, the main reason for that approach its warn developers that a modification in a 'inside' component will make consequences on many other parent components.

But the snapshot file seems wrong, many places of the code seems like that below. What can be the causes for that?

```
Filter.js
<div>
        Function.debounce
      </div>
      <div
        style={
          Object {
            "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
            "fontSize": "0.8em",
          }
        }>
        <a
          href="file:///home/<myuser>/console/node_modules/lodash/index.js"
          style={
            Object {
              "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
              "textDecoration": "none",
            }
          }>
          /home/<myuser>/console/node_modules/lodash/index.js:7667:15
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      style={
        Object {
          "marginTop": "1em",
        }
      }>
      <div>
        Filter.render
      </div>
```

- Function.debouce
- href="file://home//console
- Filter.render

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet so having to add an answer... sorry Stack Overflow gods - I'll edit the answer if the OP adds more details

Can you add some source code that produces the issue? Also how are you rendering your component and converting to JSON (react-test-renderer or enzyme)?

Without more information its hard to guess what `Function.debouce` or 
`Filter.render` is, but are you setting the `href` in your `<a>` to a local file?